# Server won't create instance of DOMDocument

Tags: php, upgrade, domdocument

I'm quite new to php, and I can't get this to work, and I don't understand why I can't..

I am using NetBeans and XAMPP locally, but I have a server "slot" at school where I upload my webpages for public.

Basically, given this code

```
<?php
echo "1";
$dom = new DOMDocument();
echo "2";
?>
```

When I run this file through XAMPP locally, it prints out "12" as it should.
But when I copy the .php file to my server, which works with everything else, it only prints out "1". It fails before it gets to "2". My conclusion is that it won't instantiate DOMDocument. How can that be? Locally i have php version 5.3.8, and on the server, it's only 5.1.6. Is this the problem?

It seemed to me like DOMDocument was supported since 5.0, but I might be wrong about that..
Anyway, I do not have permission to update this version to test this, and I can't find any information about supporting DOM in earlier versions.

Or have I forgotten something? I had kind of the same problem with JSON which isn't supported in 5.1.6, and then I could include some ("upgrade.php") file that I put next to index.php, and it worked. Any suggestions like this? Or any ideas at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that you *should* upgrade PHP, but that's not the issue. You don't have libxml or don't have php-xml installed on your server. In Fedora-based linux, it doesn't come with the default install of PHP. Run `yum install php-xml` to get it. That will auto-install its primary dependency, libxml.

Comment: Yes I found that out too, but I just got the response "yum not installed" or something. Probably some administrator-stuff to be done first in order to fix this. As I did not have much power over the server, I extended my own domain to include server-space. With latest version of php, and control over which everything, all is good. I should have done this from the start. Being the owner is far superior to being allowed to have stuff on a server on all fronts. But thanks for the answer;)